# Map slide number to source file

Tags: presentations

Hy, guys! I prepared more than 160 beamer draft slides for a Course articulated in 10, three hour, classes. It is a draft version: I plan to change some portions in the next weeks. My source is splitted (via \input) into many files, each one encompassing a "logical topic". In order to guess the mapping between slides and classes, I need to "automatically" compute the correspondence slide number <-> source file. By inspecting the log file, I find slide running numbers and loading point of each source file. I should like to produce a neat  file like

1. intro.tex
2. intro.tex
3. intro.tex
4. intro.tex
5. intro.tex
6. motiv.tex
7. motiv.tex
8. motiv.tex

...

Any hint?

Comment: This looks like a `partitioning`, so `1--5` mean `intro.tex` etc.

Comment: Can you make your actual question a bit clearer? What are the numbers in your list? The slide numbers or the frame numbers? And where do you need this list? In an extra file of like a table of contents?

Comment: Dear samcarter, thank you for your comment. The numbers are slide numbers. I need this list in an extra file. Best!

Answer (score 1):

This solution needs two LaTeX runs. The code generates two files. The .bsl file is an intermediate file and .bsx contains the list you wanted.

Oh, nearly forgot to mention: you need change every `\input` into `\rinput`.

Here are the files

intro.tex

```
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> first intro
\item<2-> second intro
\item<3-> third intro
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

motiv.tex

```
\begin{frame}{Motivaton}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> first motiv
\item<2-> second motiv
\item<3-> third motiv
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

And the main file:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\let\orig@beamer@writeslideentry\beamer@writeslidentry
\def\beamer@writeslidentry{%
  \addtocontents{bsl}{\protect\slidelistentry{\beamer@framestartpage}{\beamer@frameendpage}}%
  \orig@beamer@writeslideentry}
\AtEndDocument{\if@filesw\newwrite\tf@bsl
  \immediate\openout\tf@bsl\jobname.bsl\fi}
\newcommand{\rinput}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{bsl}{\protect\fileentry{#1}}%
  \input{#1}}
\newcommand{\currentFile}{}
\newcommand{\fileentry}[1]{\def\currentFile{#1}}
\newcount\slidelistcnt
\newcommand{\@write@sl}{}
\def\@write@sl#1\sl@end{\@writefile{bsx}{#1}}
\newcommand{\slidelistentry}[2]{%
  \slidelistcnt #1\relax
  \@tempcnta #2\advance\@tempcnta\@ne
  \loop\ifnum\slidelistcnt<\@tempcnta
    \edef\@tempa{\the\slidelistcnt. \currentFile}%
    \expandafter\@write@sl\@tempa\sl@end
    \advance\slidelistcnt\@ne
  \repeat}
\AtBeginDocument{\if@filesw\newwrite\tf@bsx
  \immediate\openout\tf@bsx\jobname.bsx\fi
  \InputIfFileExists{\jobname.bsl}{}{}}
\makeatother

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\rinput{intro.tex}
\rinput{motiv.tex}
\end{document}
```